# Event on iframe change src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm trying to catch the change of the `src` attribute of an `iframe`, I have found the method to catch the `load` event, but if the `iframe` contains some images I must wait until they are loaded before the event fires. There is a method to catch the change of the attribute instead of waiting that the pages is loaded?

Comment: How is the src being changed ? why does that occur ?

Comment: I have two main method to change the iframe source, the first outside the frame and the second inside the frame. The problem is to catch the second one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the problem with the binding to the `DOMAttrModified` event

```
$( "#myIframe" ).bind( 'DOMAttrModified', function(){
  console.log( "Attribute changed" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment "I've got two main methods to change the iframe src, first outside the iframe, second inside [...] problem catching the second", I think you should use the observer pattern.

You can implement it yourself, but no need for that as there's this library ( https://github.com/melanke/Watch.JS )

It's really easy to use, here's an example:

```
//defining a 'watcher' for an attribute
watch(exemple, "attr", function(){
    alert("attr changed!");
});
```

- this means, that you just need to watch the attribute src. Every time it changes, the callback will run

I didn't used this library myself, but I use the same pattern on Angularjs (check it out in the future, it's awesome).

Hope this helps!